# Problem updating/uninstalling Xcode

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore, software-update

So I tried updating Xcode but after the update I still got the same version of it (so there was an update still available).

I decided to uninstall it by throwing the app in the trash. The update still remains. After clicking 'Update', nothing happens and now I can't use it.

Any help on this as it is very important for me right now?

Note: I deleted the Library/Developer folder too

Comment: Have you tried downloading it directly from Apple's Developer site?  I thought you could still do that (in addition to the MAS).

Comment: @fsb It prompts me to iTunes which in turn opens the link in the AppStore of my mac.

Comment: Try https://developer.apple.com/download/ You should be able to download a stand-alone version of Xcode.

Comment: @ⱮarkƬ I thought so too but the 'download' button gets me to iTunes

Comment: Yeah, I had the wrong URL. Sorry about that. See the answer I just added.

Answer (score 1):

There is a downloads page with all past versions of all of the developer tools on it, try https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

1. Click on the "+" button to the left of "Xcode 10.2"
2. Click on the "Xcode 10.2.xip" link to download Xcode.

[image]